# How to use existing scanning software dll file using Node js for create Scanning functionality in Node js and Angular 8?

Tags: node.js, angular8

I have a requirement to create **scanning functionality using Node js API with existing scanning software** in PC. so How can I achieve that type of functionality using Node js and Angular-8.
I have already checked Dynam Twain SDK but it is available only for 30 day trail.

Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Hello, Reza Ghorbani Thanks for your reply,
No I dont have any code..! I have just implemented that Dynam Twain SDK in Angular 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing. Indeed, Dynamic Web Twain can simply run a web server with node.js to load web applications. But since you already mentioned Angular-8, you may want to use Node.js API to call Dynamic Web Twain to scan pages, right?

Here is a sample shows how to integrate Dynamic Web TWAIN JavaScript library into an Angular project.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-cli-application';
  DWObject: WebTwain;
  selectSources: HTMLSelectElement;
  ngOnInit() {
    Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.AutoLoad = false;
    Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.Containers = [{ ContainerId: 'dwtcontrolContainer', Width: '583px', Height: '513px' }];
    Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.RegisterEvent('OnWebTwainReady', () => { this.Dynamsoft_OnReady(); });
    Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.Trial = true;
    Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.ProductKey = "A-Valid-Product-Key";
    //Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.ResourcesPath = "https://tst.dynamsoft.com/libs/dwt/15.2";

    Dynamsoft.WebTwainEnv.Load();
  }
```

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/dynamsoft-dwt/angular-cli-application/tree/master/src/app).

And if you want to scan documents with Node.js API on the server-side, you can refer to the code [here](https://github.com/dynamsoft-dwt/Scan-Documents-with-Node.JS/blob/master/server.js).